# Issue with Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract name of pdf files from a string but nothing is showing up.

- string = "file_record_transcript.pdf,file_07241999.pdf,testfile_fake.pdf.tmp"
- Desired output :
  file_record_transcript.pdf, file_07241999.pdf

It is a learning example where I want to find the pattern that matches a pdf file(with a .pdf extension) and ignore other extensions like .pdf.tmp.

My approach: using regex ^.+pdf$ -> starts with any character and end with "pdf".

```
        String str = "file_record_transcript.pdf,file_07241999.pdf,testfile_fake.pdf.tmp";
        String capturePattern = "^.+pdf$";
        
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(capturePattern);
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(str);
        
        while(m1.find()) {
            System.out.println(m1.group());
            System.out.println("starts at index : "+m1.start());
            System.out.println("ends at index : "+m1.end());
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: how do you understand your pattern, and what makes you think it should match what you're expecting?

Comment: `^` and `$` represent start and end of data you are trying to search, so in case of `abc def` the `^` would represent place *before `a`* and `$` place *after `f`*. Anyway why not just *split* on comma `,` and check if each part `.endsWith(".pdf")`?

Comment: Try `[\w.]+\.pdf(?![\w.])` where the assumption is that valid characters in a filename are "word' characters and '.'.

Comment: @njzk2 I am learning regex and don't know exactly what to do here.

Comment: @Pshemo I have taken this String as an example but the main goal is to learn regex and how to get multiple matching patterns in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggested the following in a comment, but let me now explain:

`[\w.]+\.pdf(?![\w.])`

1. `[\w.]` is a "character class", meaning it matches any of the characters within the `[]`. You can also specify a range of characters using the '-' character between two other characters. For example, `[A-Za-z0-9_]` matches any character in the ranges 'A' through 'Z', 'a' through 'z' and '0' through '9' as well as the underscore character, '_'. These characters are considered to be the regex "word" characters, which has a convenient abbreviation, `\w`.  Therefore `[\w.]`, which includes the '.' character (within a character class  the period chracter, '.', does not mean "match any character"; it just matches the period. So `[\w.]` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_.]`.
2. `[\w.]+` matches *one or more* characters I described in 1.
3. `\.pdf` matches literally '.pdf'.
4. `(?![\w.])` is a *negative lookahead assertion*. It does not match any characters but asserts that the previous matches are not followed by any more word characters or '.'. This is because we do not want to match 'testfile_fake.pdf.tmp'.

[See regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KJLy1f/1)

Here is a link to a complete [Java demo](https://ideone.com/EQG02Z)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you please tell me how to implement the same pattern with regex having start(^) and end($) metacharacters?

Comment: why do you want to use the start(^) and end($) metacharacters? what purpose do you think they would serve for your use case?

Comment: I have learned about these and wanted to implement them in Java but it works on the Regex platform and not in Java. I want to understand why does this not work in Java regex.

Comment: When you say "it works on the Regex platform and not in Java", show me at [regex101](https://regex101.com/), or at least in a comment the regex you are using. The regex I posted will match filenames whose file type is '.pdf' anywhere in the string. What is your precise requirement in English? Also note that my regex does not require that the filenames be separated with any particular character of characters.

Comment: I have updated the answer adding a link to a Java demo.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial regex is trying to match an entire string that ends with `pdf` not the matches within a string that match `pdf`.

`(.+?\.pdf),` looks about right but isn't perfect https://regex101.com/r/L1voXA/1. You will want to test it with different inputs like this https://regex101.com/r/ug4E3w/2 and adjust as needed.

Matches:

- `file_record_transcript.pdf`
- `file_07241999.pdf`

Does not match:

- `testfile_fake.pdf.tmp`

Here is a complete [Java demo](https://ideone.com/EQG02Z)

Comment: This works on the regex101 platform but the same pattern is not working in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "file_record_transcript.pdf,file_07241999.pdf,testfile_fake.pdf.tmp,file_record_transcript.pdf";
        String capturePattern = "^.+pdf$";
        String tokens[] = str.split(",");
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(capturePattern);
        Matcher m1;
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            m1 = p1.matcher(tokens[i]);
            if (m1.find()) {
                System.out.println(tokens[i]);
                output.add(tokens[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.join(",", output));
```

Split the given string as tokens and then perform a regex comparison on each of the tokens. Finally, join the filtered tokens with delimiter(,).